# Android Studio ListView Image not displaying

Tags: java, android, listview

Please help me.

In my listview, I display image and text from a database.

I've encountered a problem.

When I use the .php file, the image is not displayed.
When I try to copy the result of my php to save to a .txt file and change my url, the image works.

My problem is that I want to display a image using my .php file.

Here is the code.

CategoryFragment.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/18/2015.
 */
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance(String id,String name) {
        CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", id);
        bundle.putString("name", name);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CategoryFragment () {
    }

    EditText tpid, tpname;
    String cid;
    String cname;

    String myJSON;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView productlistview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    public static String products_id = "products_id";
    public static String products_name = "products_name";
    public static String products_price = "products_price";
    public static String products_image = "products_image";

    Boolean InternetAvailable = false;
    Seocnd detectconnection;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylayout, container, false);

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        tpid = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpid);
        tpname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tpname);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String catid = getArguments().getString("id");
            String catname = getArguments().getString("name");

            tpid.setText(catid);
            tpname.setText(catname);
            cid = catid;
            cname = catname;
        }

        productlistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.productlistview);

        //new DownloadJSON().execute();

        detectconnection = new Seocnd(getActivity());
        InternetAvailable = detectconnection.InternetConnecting();
        if (InternetAvailable) {
            getProduct();
        } else {
            NointernetFragment fragment = new NointernetFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getProduct(){
        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://joehamirbalabadan.com/android/android/products.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                    jsonarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("products");

                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject p = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
                        map.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
                        map.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
                        map.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
                        // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
                // Set the adapter to the ListView
                productlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON g = new DownloadJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/28/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView products_id;
        TextView products_name;
        TextView products_price;
        ImageView products_image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in product_listview_item.xml
        products_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_id);
        products_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_name);
        products_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_price);

        // Locate the ImageView in product_listview_item.xml
        products_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.products_image);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        products_id.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_id));
        products_name.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_name));
        products_price.setText(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_price));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image), products_image);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("products_id", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_id));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("products_name", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_name));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("products_price",resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_price));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("products_image", resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

ImageLoader.java

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/28/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Here is the result..

products.php
[image]

products.txt
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your imageLoader class is buggy, I recommend to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of this custom approach, it's very fast and also manage your network operations automatically.

```
 Picasso.with(GazuntiteMainActivity.context).load(urldisplay).placeholder(R.drawable.image_loader).into(bmImage);
```

Here in the placeholder, this image is displayed till the remote image is being downloaded.

Comment: thanks.. do you have tutorial on how to use picasso with listview or gridview and json php mysql database?, also how to add picasso to android studio? i download the .jar file..

Comment: thanks.. i now add Picasso to my android studio.. do you know how can i use picasso to display my image and text from database to gridview? please help me..

Comment: Please visit here:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149

Comment: thanks.. can you also check my code because i tried to use picasso in my ListViewAdapter.. i change this code imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image), products_image); to this code Picasso.with(this).load(resultp.get(CategoryFragment.products_image)).into(products_image); but i got error in .with(this). cannot be applied..

Comment: .with(Context), it requires actually context

Comment: thanks.. i will try other way to use picasso in listview or gridview.. just want to know if there is way to add loading while the image is not displaying? because itry to run a sample code.. and it works but it display blank first before the image load.. i want to add loading.. how can i do that with picasso?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90877/discussion-between-akbar-and-joehamirbalabadan-com).